# Solving for Identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Working on Dr. Charlie Pinter's [A Book of Abstract Algebra](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486474178.html) homework 1:

Given:

$$x*y = x + 2y + 4$$

> Solve $$x*e = x$$ for e

How can I check for identity in this problem?

I'm confused since I'm not sure how to divorce `x` from `x*y` in `x + 2y + 4`.

Comment: Hint : put e instead of y and solve for e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is given: $x * y = x + 2y + 4$.
What is meant here is that this is true for any $y$.
So we can replace y with e there and we get:
$x * e = x + 2e + 4$.
From there on, after using that $x * e=x$,
the solution becomes trivial.